# SQL Extract Values from a String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I extract values from a string?  I'm trying to separate into 3 new columns.  A separate column for city, state and zipcode.

I've tried

```
select address2,
left(address2, charindex('',address2)-1)
from table
```

and ---when I try the below code I get "Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function"

```
,LTRIM(substring(a.Address2, CHARINDEX(' ', a.Address2)+1, CHARINDEX(' ', substring(a.address2, charindex(' ',
a.address2)+1, len(a.address2)))-1))
```

I can break out the city (except for West Warwick) using the following code, but not sure how to make it work for state and zip.  This also removes the error.

```
SUBSTRING(Address2,1,CHARINDEX(' ', a.address2+ ' ')-1) as city
```

Any ideas what to try?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your zip codes and your states are all the same length. If that is true, you should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(a.Address2,LEN(a.Address2) - 13) AS City,
    RIGHT(LEFT(a.Address2,LEN(a.Address2) - 11),2) AS State,
    RIGHT(a.Address2,10) AS Zip_Code
FROM
    table;
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

Create the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Address2 VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES
    ('SAN DIEGO CA 92128-1234'),
    ('WEST WARWICK RI 02893-1349'),
    ('RICHMOND IN 47374-9409');
```

The query:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(Address2,LEN(Address2) - 13) AS City,
    RIGHT(LEFT(Address2,LEN(Address2) - 11),2) AS State,
    RIGHT(Address2,10) AS Zip_Code
FROM
    MyTable;
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Do I have to have a where clause?  I still get "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: I did update the `State` logic - I was off by one. If you still get the error, that means there are records where either the `state` or the `zip` (or both) are not the same length as those in the example data you provided.

Comment: This seems to remove the error, but I only know how to make it work for one column.  (except West Warwick)  SUBSTRING(Address2,1,CHARINDEX(' ', address2+ ' ')-1) as city

Comment: Not sure why you are using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX as I did not suggest that in my answer. I updated my answer, too, to include each step and the output.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your response, and for helping me.  I continued to get the error message and so I continued to work at it. The sample data above is only a sub-set to show as an example of what I have to work with.  I would need to create a temp table for every city, state and zip in the USA to make this work.  I'm not sure I want to do that.  Any other suggestions or ways to make this work.  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to create temp tables for each? If the above does not work for all cases, I can only assume it is because the format of the data is not the same for all records - is that correct? Can you provide examples of the records that fail?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 3 parts (City/State/Zip) you can take advantage of a function called [parsename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 and later. (The original intent of the function is to parse out object names.)

Using a combination of the `replace` and `parsename` functions will allow you to be able to separate the data into 3 parts, even if the length of the State (not likely) or the Zip (more likely) change.

**Example Data:**

```
create table #my_table
    (
        address2 varchar(75) not null
    )

insert into #my_table values ('CONNERSVILLE IN 47331-3351')
insert into #my_table values ('WEST WARWICK RI 02893-1349')
insert into #my_table values ('RICHMOND IN 47374-9409')
insert into #my_table values ('WILLIAMSBURG IN 47393-9617')
insert into #my_table values ('FARMERSVILLE OH 45325-9226')
--this record is an example of a likely scenario for when the zip length would change.
insert into #my_table values ('WILLIAMSBURG IN 47393')
```

**Solution:**

```
with len_vals as 
    (
        select t.address2
        , len(parsename(replace(t.address2,' ','.'), 1)) as zip_len
        , len(parsename(replace(t.address2,' ','.'), 2)) as st_len
        from #my_table as t
        group by t.address2
    )
select left(a.address2, len(a.address2) - b.zip_len - b.st_len  - 2) as city
, substring(a.address2, len(a.address2) - b.zip_len - 2, b.st_len) as st
, right(a.address2, b.zip_len) as zip_code
from #my_table as a
inner join len_vals as b on a.address2 = b.address2
```

**Results:**

[image: exampleDataResults]